# How to get OnClick in DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener?

Tags: android, datepicker

I am using the following method to pop up the dialog to pick the date.

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                dobYear = year;
                dobMonth = monthOfYear;
                dobDay = dayOfMonth;
                if(isEighteenYearOld()){
                   //display the current date
                    dateDisplay();
                } else{
                   Toast.makeText(mContext, "You must be 18 year old", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }  
            } 

        };
```

I know that onDateSet we can get the selected date. But what i am trying is if the date selected is younger than 18 years i need to alert the user. I have tried above code but it close the dialog and gone back to the activity.

I want to stay in the dialog until user selects the date which is 18 years old.I am not sure how to get the onclick event in the dialog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Date Picker Dialog you are using is deprecated so I recommend you to don't use that.

You can implement the Date picker in two ways(that I know of)

1. Using DialogFragment
2. Using AlertDialog

**Using DialogFragment:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    EditText text;
    Button b;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                DateDialogFragment datepicker=new DateDialogFragment();
                datepicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "showDate");
            }
        });
    }

    public class DateDialogFragment extends DialogFragment  implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

        public DateDialogFragment()
        {
        }
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
            int year=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            showSetDate(year,monthOfYear,dayOfMonth);
        }

        }

    public void showSetDate(int year,int month,int day) {
    text.setText(year+"/+"+month+"/"+day);
    }
}
```

Check this sample and implement the same in your Activity.

**Using Alert Dialog**:

Using the second one is pretty simple

Create layout in your res/layout folder and place DatePicker in the layout

```
 LayoutInflater  inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);
DatePicker picker=(DatePicker)view.findViewById(R.id.datepicker);

  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
 builder.setView(view).
        builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles)
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // User cancelled the dialog
                   }
               });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you said in you first method how do you handle onClick when the dialog appears?

Comment: No need to handle it separately it comes with the two button set and cancel, And when you set the date It will come in the onDateSet Everyting handled by android

Comment: Yes i know that. But what i want is i have to validate before coming it to onDataSet. As i explained in my question.

Comment: @Vino You will get the selected date in onDateSet.. There you can validate the date, if the date is less than 18  than you'll show a error message and display the date picker dialog again its in your hand

Comment: thanks yes i can do that. but is there anyway of validating before the dialog disappears

Comment: Just think once generally, How do you get the which haven't set..? i.e you need click on set button to set date until than DatePicker don't know the Date You've selected. it may possible after you click on set button... I'll try to explore it

Comment: Don't use Dialog because it is not working in most of devices..Mainly in Samsung phones.. I have got a lot of issues after delivering the app I some how managed by using DialogFragment...You can mark this as answer if it helps you..

Comment: @Vino use second approach, and in the onclick method get the selected date and check whether it is >18 or ..if true than close if not Post a error message

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Pragnani. I will try and let you know +1

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a custom implementation of such dialog, you have to subclass `DatePickerDialog` to achieve such behavior. You can't block the dialog from closing just with `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener`.

Unfortunatelly, implementations of the dialog vary with different API levels, so it's not that trivial to get the desired behavior with subclassing. You need to add some hacks to make it work reliably.

I've created a sample implementation that blocks the dialog from closing unless an appropriate date is set (or a cancel or back button is hit). Adjust it to display your alert to the users, the best place is the else branch in `onClick()` method.

```java
class CheckingDatePickerDialog extends DatePickerDialog {

    private int year;
    private boolean cancel = false;
    private boolean isCancelable = true;

    CheckingDatePickerDialog(Context context, OnDateSetListener callBack, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        super(context, callBack, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        this.year = year;
    }

    CheckingDatePickerDialog(Context context, int theme, OnDateSetListener callBack, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        super(context, theme, callBack, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        this.year = year;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // allow closing the dialog with cancel button
        Button btn = getButton(BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
        if (btn != null) {
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    cancel = true;
                    dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setCancelable(boolean flag) {
        isCancelable = false;
        super.setCancelable(flag);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // allow closing the dialog with back button if the dialog is cancelable
        cancel = isCancelable;
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    private boolean isOldEnough() {
        // test if the date is allowed
        return year <= 1994;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // necessary for some Honeycomb devices
            DatePicker dp = getDatePicker();
            this.year = dp.getYear();
        }

        if (isOldEnough()) {
            // OnDateSetListener is called in super.onClick()
            super.onClick(dialog, which);  
        } else {
            // place your alert here
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // on some Honeycomb devices called only with the first change
        // necessary for devices running Android 2.x
        this.year = year;
        super.onDateChanged(view, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void dismiss() {
        if (cancel || isOldEnough()) {
            // do not allow the dialog to be dismissed unless a cancel or back button was clicked
            super.dismiss();
        }
    }
};
```