# How do I change a DatePickerDialog's default date from today's date to a user selected date?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-datepicker

I have a DatePickerDialog that opens in a fragment.  On first open, the dialog's default date displays today's date.  The user then selects a date.  When the dialog is dismissed, I set an EditText line with the user selected date.

The next time the dialog opens, I want to show the user's previously selected date, not today's date.  Should I create a Bundle in onDateSet function to save the selected date?  If so, how do I use the Bundle to populate the dialog the next time it is opened?  Would an emptiness test on the EditText line be useful so that the dialog does not populate with today's date if the line has a date already set?

partial DatePickerFragment file:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

private int currentyear;
private int currentmonth;
private int currentday;

public DatePickerFragment() {
}

public interface OnDateEnteredListener {
     void OnDateEntered(int year, int month, int day);
}
OnDateEnteredListener mListener;


// Set up a Calendar object that will capture the current date for the DatePickerDialog to use.
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final Bundle datebundle = this.getArguments();
    currentyear = datebundle.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    currentmonth = datebundle.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    currentday = datebundle.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

if(currentyear != 0){
        DatePickerDialog dateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this.getActivity(), this, currentyear, currentmonth, currentday);
        dateDialog.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(true);
        dateDialog.getDatePicker().setSpinnersShown(false);
        dateDialog.setTitle("Select a Due Date");
        return dateDialog;
    }
    else {
        // Create three variables to capture the current date.
        currentyear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        currentmonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        currentday = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        // Create a DatePickerDialog which is a simple dialog containing a DatePicker.  Use the current date
        // as the default date in the DatePicker.  The new instance of DatePickerDialog is created by passing
        // 5 parameters/arguments to the constructor and returning it.
        DatePickerDialog dateDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this.getActivity(), this, currentyear, currentmonth, currentday);
        dateDialog.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(true);
        dateDialog.getDatePicker().setSpinnersShown(false);
        dateDialog.setTitle("Select a Due Date");
        return dateDialog;
    }
}


public void onDateSet (DatePicker view,int year, int month, int day) {
     mListener.OnDateEntered(year,month,day);
...

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

partial Activity file:

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerFragment.OnDateEnteredListener {

  int currentyear;
  int currentmonth;
  int currentday;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.input);

    fListenerEditText = (ListenerEditText) findViewById(R.id.FEditText);

    fListenerEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus && (fListenerEditText.getText().length() == 0)) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        Bundle datebundle = new Bundle();
              datebundle.putInt("YEAR", currentyear);
              datebundle.putInt("MONTH", currentmonth);
              datebundle.putInt("DAY", currentday);
              newFragment.setArguments(datebundle);
              newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
           }
        }
    });

  @Override
  public void onDateEntered(int year, int month, int day) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think, You should just create a new OnDateSetListener when you create your DatePickerDialog. This way, you will have multiple "onDateSet" methods.

Comment: Ok, so how would the OnDateSetListener be used in onCreateDialog?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15031018/5202007

Comment: For the answer from Pragnani it looks like the code sets today's date as the default date for the dialog.  It appears that the selected date from onDateSet is not used in onCreateDialog.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the user picks the date, use the following to communicate the data back to your Activity once the dialog closes (communicating data from a fragment back to the starting activity): http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Once you receive the values back in your activity, use the following when starting your DatePickerFragment:

```
DatePickerFragment datepickerfragment = new DatePickFragment();

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("YEAR", currentyear);
bundle.putInt("MONTH", currentmonth);
bundle.putInt("DAY", currentday);
datepickerfragment.Arguments = bundle;

fragmentmanager.BeginTransaction().Add(R.layout.container, datepickerfragment).Commit();
```

Where currentyear, currentmonth, and currentday are the calendar values the user selected. Retrieve the values in your dialog fragment next time it opens as follow:

```
int year = this.Arguments.getInt("YEAR");
int month = this.Arguments.getInt("MONTH");
int day = this.Arguments.getInt("DAY");
```

Now you can set the dialog's date to year, month, day obtained from the previous DatePickerFragment's values.

EDIT: 
To set the values, in onCreateDialog(Bundle bundle) do as follows:

```
....
int year = this.Arguments.getInt("YEAR");
int month = this.Arguments.getInt("MONTH");
int day = this.Arguments.getInt("DAY");

if(year != null){
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}else{
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so are the calendar values the user selected set in the Fragment's onDateSet method or in onCreateDialog?

Comment: @AJW They are set in onCreateDialog.

Comment: Ok, so how do I write the choice in onCreateDialog between the three other "current" variables that capture today's date and the three for the user selected date?

Comment: So if there is a previously selected date then year will not be null, so create the dialog with the Bundle args.  If there is no year, then it is the first time the dialog is being created so just use today's date.  Correct?

Comment: @AJW Correct. That is what was intended.

Comment: Ok great.  You mentioned in the beginning about communicating the selected date from the fragment back to the activity.  Do I do that with a Bundle also and putInt?

Comment: @AJW No, no bundles involved. Try reading that guide. You basically pass the data back by implementing an interface (located in the DialogFragment) in your activity.

Comment: Ok I will read the guide.  Also, in the fragment you reference "DAY" for putInt and getInt above.  Should both of those be "DAY_OF_MONTH"?

Comment: @AJW It actually doesn't matter what you call them. Just as long as the string keys are the same for putInt and getInt.

Comment: Ok.  I read the guide and I understand setting up a listener that calls back from the Fragment to the host Activity.  But if the user selected date is not sent back via a Bundle then how is the data delivered with the interface?

Comment: @AJW The interface that you're implementing in your activity will accept the year, month and day in its parameters

Comment: Ok I will give a try.  Thanks and I appreciate your time and answering all of my questions.  Accepting your answer as best and upvoting now.

Comment: One more question for the Activity code:  when the Fragment is first created and the the default date of today's date is shown, does Android ignore the empty Bundle?  Will an empty Bundle throw an exception or does Android just ignore the bundle and Arguments code?

Comment: @AJW It will complain that the int values are null. An if statement should be able to circumvent this

Comment: Android Studio complains about the != null, stating "Operator != cannot be  applied to 'int'.  Can I just use zero instead:  "if(year != 0)"?

Comment: Also, Activity is throwing an error with the interface code:  "Activity is not abstract and does not override abstract method OnDateEntered in OnDateEnteredListener."  Thoughts?

Comment: @AJW null is not the same as 0. Null means a value has not been assigned to it. Therefore a string value could be null. You can definitely apply != to an int type, please send me your code. The second error you're receiving is because you aren't implementing the interface properly. Try to follow the tutorial as closely as possible, it will work it's just a bit confusing at first.

Comment: Latest code is now shown above.  Hopefully am making progress but Android Studio won't allow "currentyear !=null..." and still researching listener error in activity.  Please advise.

Comment: I was able to get interface set up with no complaints from Android Studio.  Basically I had to add the onDateEntered method (in the interface of the Fragment) to the Activity.  I am able to run the code but no luck, the default date (today's date) still shows in the dialog box when the user trys to edit the date.  Any ideas?

Comment: @AJW Use if(!datebundle.IsEmpty) instead of if(currentyear !=0). Your code isn't working because you never assigned currentyear, currentmonth, and currentday in OnDateEntered in your activity. This means when you start your dialogfragment you aren't putting the user selected date values in your fragment arguments. In OnDateEntered, add "currentyear = year; currentmonth = month; currentday = day;"

Comment: Ok.  Android Studio won't accept "if(!datebundle.IsEmpty)".  Says "Cannot resolve symbol 'IsEmpty'."

Comment: @AJW that's because it's how it's written in C#. Java has an equivalent method... databundle.isEmpty()