# Returning date from android date picker to calling method

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I am iterating through a list of date entries. If the date entry is not a valid date, i call a DatePickerDialog. What I don't understand is, how I can return the chosen date to the calling method, so that I can use it

the calling funtion:

```
else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Not a valid date");
            // get actual date
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

            // open date picker
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, this, year, month, day);
            String dateString;
            datePickerDialog.setMessage("Wrong date: " + helpList.get(0));
            datePickerDialog.show();
            // use chosen date
            if (chosenDate.length() > 0) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Date will be set: " + chosenDate);
            }
        }
```

the onDateSet method:

```
   @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

    Calendar aCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    aCalendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    String theDate = formatter.format(aCalendar.getTime());
    Log.i(TAG, "Chosen date formatet: " + theDate);
    chosenDate = theDate;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027454/how-to-get-onclick-in-datepickerdialog-ondatesetlistener

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DialogFragment and use it in your activity like this:

```
   DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
   newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

The DatePickerFragment should extend DialogFragment and can look like this:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), dpickerListener, year, month, day);
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            EditText dateEditText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(getArguments().getInt("editTextId"));
            GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
            cal.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            fmt.setCalendar(cal);
            String dateFormatted = fmt.format(cal.getTime());
            dateEditText.setText(dateFormatted);
            dateEditText.clearFocus();
        }
    };
}
```

Note how the activity is accessed through this line:

```
EditText dateEditText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(getArguments().getInt("editTextId"));
```

This way you can implement some logic in your calling activity. Ofcourse you can just invoke a method in the calling activity - something like this:

```
((MyActivity)getActivity()).doSomethingWithData(dateFormatted);
```